# How to call getJSON inside DataTable render function?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables, getjson

I just started to learn dataTables.

Is it possible to use getJson() inside DataTable render function to render table data?

I'm getting undefined from console.log(category); at the moment.

Am I missing something here?

```
function loadHelpdeskTickets(id) {

$.getJSON(HELPDESKTICKETS_URL + "?filter[where][customerId]=" + id, function(data) {

    var table = $('#helpdesk_table').DataTable({
        data: data,
        "order": [
            [1, "desc"]
        ],
        "processing": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "paging": true,
        "columns": [{
                data: "id"
            },
            {
                data: "ticketOpen",
                render: function(data, type, row) {

                    date = new Date(data);
                    return date.toLocaleString("en-GB");
                }
            },
            {
                data: "category",
                render: function(data, type, row) {

                    var category;

                    $.getJSON(HELPDESKQUESTIONS_URL + "?filter[where][id]=" + data, function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                            console.log(val.type);
                            category = val.type;
                        });
                    });

                    console.log(category);
                    return category;
                }
            },
            {
                data: "userId"
            },
            {
                data: "installerId"
            }

        ]
    });
});
```

}

Comment: Looks like getJSON is a ajax method and so your console.log(category) will be set before getJSON call is completed. try doing console.log(category) inside of $.each i.,e where you are setting category.

Comment: That wouldn't help me cause I need to return that value on the end.

And I can't use return inside ajax call either.

Comment: This is a really, really, *really* bad approach.  You must load the categories upfront, include the category in the original request or at least maintain some kind of lookup list so multiple contionusly AJAX calls is avoided.

Comment: Thanks @davidkonrad